# Element not Getting the correct automation id what can i do?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.uitest

I put an automation id to a label:
[Label's code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrGAW.jpg)

and in my test, I used Repl()
and all the labels are not with the correct automation id (the text and the automation Id needs to be the same)
[Test's Repl() tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl0Q2.jpg)

Comment: Could you show some codes ?

Comment: Are you saving this issue on iOS as well? Take a look at this https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/97202/why-do-views-in-my-app-not-have-ids

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT what code do you need
I posted the app code and the automated test code?

Comment: @TrentAlexanderArnold Your  automated test codes.

Comment: When you set the labels text via binding you don't really need the AutomationId. You can easily see them using the Text query [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.uitest.queries.appquery.text?view=xamarin-uitest-sdk)